# How to get only the last folder and filename of a path?

Tags: python

How can I get the last folder and the filename of a path in Python?

I am doing:

```
pre_l="/this/is/the/absolute/path/from_here/thefile.txt"
pt=os.path.join(".",os.path.basename(os.path.dirname(pre_l)),os.path.basename(pre_l))
```

Is there a simpler way?

Comment: What's the expected output for the given path `pre_l`?

Comment: @AbhijitSarkar I think either './from_here/thefile.txt' or 'from_here/thefile.txt'

Comment: `./from_here/thefile.txt`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a very simple way to do this,
the idea is that:

1. split the path with `/`
2. select the folder and file name
3. join them with slash

Implementation:

```py
pre_l="/this/is/the/absolute/path/from_here/thefile.txt"
pt = "./" + "/".join(pre_l.split('/')[-2:]) #output: ./from_here/thefile.txt
```

Answer (score 1):

This is pretty easy with `pathlib` - the `parts` attribute breaks down the path components into a tuple. `pathlib` was introduced with Python 3.4.

```
>>> from pathlib import Path
>>> p = Path("/this/is/the/absolute/path/from_here/thefile.txt")
>>> p.parts
('/', 'this', 'is', 'the', 'absolute', 'path', 'from_here', 'thefile.txt')
```

so this should give what you're looking for:

```
>>> "./" + "/".join(p.parts[-2:])
'./from_here/thefile.txt'
```

Answer (score 1):

I recommend using the [pathlib](https://docs.python.org/3/library/pathlib.html) module specifically meant for handling paths, not regex.

```
from pathlib import Path
p = Path('/this/is/the/absolute/path/from_here/thefile.txt')
x = p.parts[-2:]
p = Path(*x)
print(p) # from_here/thefile.txt
```

Answer (score 0):

Consider using `re`

```py
import os, re
pre_l = "/this/is/the/absolute/path/from_here/thefile.txt"
pt = os.sep.join(['.'] + re.split(r'[\//]', pre_l)[-2:])
```

Answer (score 0):

This is a solution I created when I was having the same problem

```py
import platform
slashchr = '\\' if platform.system()=='Windows' else '/'
pre_l = "/this/is/the/absolute/path/from_here/thefile.txt"
temp_list = pre_l.split(slashchr)
pt = slashchr.join(temp_list[-2:])
```

Comment: `os.path.sep` already provides the logic to choose the path separator depending on your platform. You are basically reinventing the `os.path.join` and `os.path.split` functions, which are now essentially superseded by `pathlib` anyway.

Comment: Ahh okay, i wasnt aware of that, thank you